# What and how to store to keep users logged in in a React Native App with Firebase backend?

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, firebase-authentication

in my react native app, initially, the users will be anonymous. Later on they will have the chance to sign in with a well-known user, but even without signing in I would like to keep data about an (anonymous) user between sessions. How can I achieve this? What and how should I store about the user locally to "re-authenticate" her even as an anonymous user?

## Anonymous users

As Firebase is preferably restricted to authenticated users, I should somehow be able to keep the user logged in even if she was an anonymous user.

I know that each user has a uid, and I could store it locally, outside of Firebase. How can I achieve this?

## Authenticated users

I know that in this case (1) firebase tries to keep the session, (2) I can store the credentials locally to reauthenticate if needed.

## Basic questions

- how can I re-authenticate an anonymous user? is it needed at all or does firebase keep the session here too?
- is there a way to use redux-persist together with firebase to store the `uid` and/or credentials for each user outside of firebase?

## Tech stack

It's a react native app.
I plan to use https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase for Firebase support and would prefer to use `redux-persist`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Auth persists the user via AsyncStorage in react-native. In order to properly get the user state, you need to listen to onAuthStateChanged listener:

```
// Call this function when app mounts
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // currentUser should be non null.
  } else {
    // no user logged in. currentUser is null.
  }
});
```